# How do I describe when someone is in possession of something they haven't been given

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm specifically referring to a someone which one *shouldn't* have, from the speaker's perspective.

**For example:**

> "We shouldn't allow the government to get comfortable with this ?????? power."

Where the '?' describes the fact that the power shouldn't be theirs or is unfounded. (1 word)

I think the word I'm looking for is closely synonymous with 'undeserving', as I don't think 'undeserving' is grammatically correct in this context...

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151892/discussion-on-question-by-dom-how-do-i-describe-when-someone-is-in-possession-of); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 21):

... with this **[arrogated](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&sca_esv=6bf8d48f10a145ec&sca_upv=1&sxsrf=AC&q=arrogated%20power&tbm=bks&source=lnms&prmd=ivhsnmbtz&sa=X&biw=1356&bih=681&dpr=1)** power.

All dictionaries will have a definition similar to "taken or claimed without right or justification".

Comment: This is the best answer here IMO.

Answer (score 10):

To focus on *shouldn't* I think **usurped** is appropriate [[Cambridge Dictionary *usurp*]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/usurped):

> to take control of a position of power, especially without having the right to
>
> > We shouldn't allow the government to get comfortable with this usurped power.

Less obscure could be *illegitimate* [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/illegitimate):

> not legal or fair:
>
> > The rebels regard the official parliament as illegitimate.

Answer (score 10):

[Unmerited](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unmerited) is a good match for your meaning:

> not adequately earned or deserved : not merited

Answer (score 9):

**Unwarranted** would work in this context.  *Warranted* means (OED)

> Allowed by law or authority; approved, justified, sanctioned.

and so *unwarranted* would be something that not approved, justified, or sanctioned.

Comment: *unwarranted* can also mean disproportionate to the needs of the occasion; because of that ambiguity, I would not use it in the given context.

Comment: *unwarranted power* wins the Ngram over *unmerited power* and *arrogated power*.

Comment: Ngrams don't show usage in a particular sense, just absolute usage.

Comment: That's why you can't add *assume power* or it blows the curve. "too much political baggage"

Answer (score 5):

In a political register, *assumed* works:

- *We shouldn't allow the government to get comfortable with this assumed power*.

> **assume**: seize; usurp
>
> - *assume control*

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assumed)]

(In other contexts, *assumed* has of course other default meanings.)

Comment: Even though it wins the Ngram, it has too much political baggage. Are we talking about overthrowing the entire government, or just pissed off that garbage pickup is now on Thursdays.

Comment: The same can be said for all the other answers; the context ('We shouldn't allow the government to get comfortable with this Ø power') disambiguates in each case.

Answer (score 5):

*undeserving* is wrong because it would describe how the power acts. But the same concept can be applied correctly with *undeserved*, which refers to how the power was achieved -- it didn't deserve it. Similarly, if someone receives praise for something they didn't actually do, we would say they're "undeserved compliments".

Answer (score 4):

***Ill-gotten*** is a term indicating that something has been gained through illegal or unfair means. It implies not just that the thing in question should not be held by the person who has it, but also that they did something unscrupulous to get it.

Answer (score 3):

A less specific term, which might be more accessible to a wider audience, is *purloined*.

purloin (v): to appropriate wrongfully and often by a breach of trust (Merriam-Webster.com)[1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/purloin)

"legislators from the rural prison counties often use this **purloined power** to vote against the interests of the urban communities from which prison inmates most typically come. " -- [Prisoners of the Census](https://www.prisonersofthecensus.org/news/2005/09/26/phantom/) (about prisoners counting towards the Census power of the locations where they are imprisoned without being able to vote.)

"This meritless lawsuit is designed to rally progressives to defend California’s **purloined power** to regulate fuel economy." -- [Fuel Economy: California](https://cei.org/opeds_articles/fuel-economy-californias-empty-suit/) (about claims of inappropriate government lobbying activity.)

Answer (score 2):

One legal term is

> **ultra vires**
> <sub>*adjective*</sub>
>
> beyond the legal power or authority of the person performing an action
>
> *The company's actions in entering into a contract with him were ultra vires, and therefore the contract was void.*
> *A shareholder could restrain the company from undertaking ultra vires activities.*

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ultra-vires).

The sentence could be

> We shouldn't allow the government to get comfortable using this **ultra vires** power.

Or more concisely

> We shouldn't allow the government to use this **ultra vires** power.

Comment: As the quotations make clear, an act that is performed ultra vires is void, because one doesn't really have the power to perform it. That doesn't seem to be quite what the OP has in mind. In the OP's example, as I understand it, the government does have the power, and its acts are not void; it's just that it has obtained the power in a way that is, from the speaker's viewpoint, improper.

Comment: @jsw the question also states "the power is unfounded" IOW it doesn't actually have that power.

Comment: "Power" isn't ultra vires, actions are.

Answer (score 1):

There are several good answers here, but I'll add [misappropriated](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/misappropriate) and its lightly harsher cousin [malappropriated](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/malappropriate), which both mean to take control of something inappropriately.

Misappropriated means that a party was in a position of trust to manage or control something, but then abused that trust by exceeding the granted authority, usually by directing resources away from their intended target for personal gain or benefit, or by exceeding the amount of usage allowed.

Misappropriated is often used in financial terms to refer to someone making use of funds in a way that they are not supposed to, but it can also be used to refer to misuse of other things, such as property, materials, or as in this example, power.

> When the rule of law has been ignored on a political whim, we feel it reverberate in ways that seem to shake us to the core. [Misappropriated power](https://www.suffolknewsherald.com/2015/09/19/the-hedgehog-concept-and-the-rule-of-law/) thrives where rule of law ends.

Malappropriated has a slightly stronger implication of deliberate malice, but both indicate dishonesty and a violation of trust.

Answer (score 0):

***Unchecked*** is frequently used in your context in the sense of "growing more than deserved".

> "We shouldn't allow the government to get comfortable with this
> ***unchecked*** power."

Collins:

> **[unchecked](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unchecked)**
> *ADJECTIVE*
> If something harmful or **undesirable** is left unchecked, nobody controls it or prevents it from growing or
> developing.
>
> This provision gives the president total and ***unchecked*** power.

Comment: But this doesn't say how exactly the power was gotten in the first place, which is the demand of the question. You can say it's the consequence of arrogated power. BTW, I'm not the downvoter.

Answer (score -2):

I think we are all agreed that one should not steal, and that stealing is a way of coming into unauthorised possession of something:

> "We shouldn't allow the government to get comfortable with this **kleptocratic** power."

OED

> **Etymology: klepto**- Forming words in which it has the sense ‘theft, thieving’, as kleptocracy, kleptomania. **Plus -cracy:** From French
> ‑cratie < post-classical Latin ‑cratia < Greek κρατία (in compounds)
> power, rule, < κράτος strength, might, rule, authority.
>
> **kleptocratic Of, designating, or relating to a kleptocracy.**
>
> 2001 After a decade of robber baron capitalism that burned Western
> investors, these bosses now say that kleptocratic practices proved a
> dead end for a country with an annual gross domestic product of $300
> billion. Business Week 12 November 70/1

> **kleptocracy**: A ruling body or order of thieves. Also, government by thieves; a nation ruled by this kind of government.

Comment: I would read that as “power that allows or encourages the state to become more kleptocratic”, rather than “stolen power”.

Comment: kleptocratic power would be power that enables rule by stealing.

Comment: @fectin I think you need to consider the tenor of the example, and realise that this is a more figurative/emotional use.